# Issue receiving Form data with Flask

Tags: python, forms, post, flask, request

A rather odd one that I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using a Wordpress plugin called webhooks which sends data off to an API endpoint to be processed. That API endpoint is managed by a **Flask** application.

```
@app.route('/<source>/<reason>/post/send', methods=['POST'])
def send(source, reason):

    uuid = request.form.get('uuid')

    form = request.form

    return jsonify(result={ "status": 200, "form": form, "source": source, "reason": reason })
```

Essentially I was thinking what is going on because uuid was returned as "null" so I decided to return the response of the form itself:

```
{ "result": { "form": { "{\"uuid\":\"sdsdfsdfsdf\",\"name\":\"Michael Roberts\",\"email\":\"michael.j.roberts@booboo.com\"}": "" }, "reason": "tommy", "source": "timmy", "status": 200 } }
```

The above is the smallest example I can give - but essentially how on earth do I reference uuid, email, name etc??

Answer (score 0):

docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request

- `request.data` Contains the incoming request data as **string** in case it came with a **mimetype** Flask does not handle.
- `request.form`: the key/value pairs in the body, from a HTML post form, or JavaScript request that **isn't** JSON encoded

So you can try request.data if it has the correct mimetype (application json) or encode the request.form to dict with `json.loads(request.form)` then access uuid